# sort list value after comparing a word in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

i want to sort list tag after comparing with a word like if more than one statements having word "one" so it should be sort first, then check for other word in other statement like "two" in remaining statements so this statement having "two" word should come after statement that contain "one".  so guys please help me how we should write logic . look once my code that is i used for only for sort alphabetically ...   **(on the basis of status that is given below in code )**
**Example** :  like

- manoj kumar
- rohit koul
- sachin kumar

so in these three list i want to sort first who containing "kumar" string and then etc ..

```
<script id="template" type="text/html">
<ul class="checklist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-autodividers="true"     id="mylist">
{{#container}}
{{#nid}}<li><a href="checklist-detail.html?nid={{nid}}">{{name}} - {{status}} {{#date}}<br/>
   <span class="due-date">{{date}}</span>{{/date}}</a></li>{{/nid}}
      {{/container}}
 </ul>
</script>

look once my javascript code but this is not for my desire code it is only
 for sort  alphabetically (help me in this code that how to i write 
  condition or logic for sort according to particular word comparison)
      var mylist = $('ul');
       var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
      listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
      var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
     var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
     return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
 $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

Comment: Could you plz add a few examples of texts you are trying to compare?

Comment: create fiddle for your code

Comment: Example :  like <ul><li>manoj kumar</li> <li>rohit koul</li><li>sachin kumar</li></ul>  so in these three list i want to sort first who containing "kumar" string and then etc ..

Answer (score 0):

You can give the tags a score based on whether they contain a word from your predefined list of ordered words. For example:

```
var ordered_words = ["kumar", "koul", "simon"]
var tags = ["manoj kumar", "rohit koul", "sachin kumar", "simon f (me)"]
var scored_tags = []

var i = 0, tag
while (tag = tags[i]) {
    var j = 0, word, found = false
    while (found == false && j < ordered_words.length) {
        word = ordered_words[j]
        if (tag.indexOf(word) != -1) {
            scored_tags.push({tag: tag, score: j})
            found = true
        }
        j++
    }
    i++
}
console.log(scored_tags)
```

This will output:

```
[ { tag: 'manoj kumar', score: 0 },
  { tag: 'rohit koul', score: 1 },
  { tag: 'sachin kumar', score: 0 },
  { tag: 'simon f (me)', score: 2 } ]
```

You can then sort this array using the score parameter using something like this:

```
scored_tags.sort(function(a, b) {
      var compA = a.score
      var compB = b.score
      return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Here's the code for you to play with:

http://repl.it/Yil/2

Comment: Great, thanks, good to hear - if it is working for you, I'd appreciate an upvote for my answer!